# Laravel: where not expired?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a column called `expires_at` and its a datetime in my MySQL database. I need to fetch records where expires_at hasn't been met, how can I do this?

My current query looks like this 
`Model::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();`

Comment: the expired_at, you want to compare it with the current time?

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
use App\Model;

$now = Carbon::now();
Model::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
     ->where('expired_at', '>', $now)
     ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#where-clauses

If you're looking to compare with current date, try:

```
Model::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
     ->whereDate('expired_at', '>', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
     ->get();
```

Comment: You need to compare with a date. The date format I've placed is the dateformat of mysql. You can use Carbon, php's date, you can even find another way to get the date, but in the end, you need to compare with mysql's date format. That's the purpose of your question, where 'expires_at hasn't been met' - the being met is a date (with or without hours)

Comment: whereDate() does not compare time CMIIW. Use the usual where() to compare both date and time.